# Establish if an array of objects contains an entry based on a key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using javascript/es6, how do I write a one-liner which returns a boolean specifying whether `data` contains an entry for `theId == 3`:

```
let data = [{"name":"Tom",address:"Here","theId":"1"},{"name":"Neve",address:"There","theId":"2"}]
```

if I am confined to organising `data` in this manner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and ES6 arrow functions.

```js
let data = [{"name":"Tom",address:"Here","theId":"1"},{"name":"Neve",address:"There","theId":"2"}]
var check = data.some(arr => arr.theId == 3);
console.log(check)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.filter(item => item.theId == 3).length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit complicated for one liner.

```
data.some((item) => {return item.theId === "3"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method for Arrays.

This method iterates through each element of an Array until it finds the first case where it can return true and then stops further iterations.

```
data.some((obj) => {
  return obj.theId === 3;
});
```

The above code will return true if on finding the first element with `theId : '3'` otherwise it will return false;

Example https://jsbin.com/yubezizana/2/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

this is what I came up with:

```
data.map(x => x.theId).indexOf("3") > -1;
```

Comment: This will not work if the element is the first one in the array.